# I can't call function in LLVM Tutorial: Table of Contents Chapter6 code

Tags: c++, llvm

I compiled my toy.cpp in llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/Chapter6/toy.cpp

Compile Success But executed my code

```
ready> extern printd(x);
ready> Read exxtern:
declare double @printd(double)

ready> printd(40);
ready> Failure value returned from cantFail wrapped call
UNREACHABLE executed at /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Error.h:716!
```

I can't call my function

Comment: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-June/123963.html <- this problem looks similar, got no response on llvm mailing list